# How to add a static ad Banner into a UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am looking to add AdMob banners throughout my app. I have placed them into the bottom of every screen and it works correctly, but not entirely when it comes to UIViewControllers.

When I put an add onto the UITableViewController it is starting in the correct spot on the bottom of the screen, but when I scroll the table it moves with it. I need the ad to statically stay at the bottom of the screen as I scroll the table.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)displayGAD
{
    // The frame of the banner is initialized off screen.
    // If an ad loads then it will animate onto the screen.
    self.bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,
                                                                      self.view.frame.size.height,
                                                                      GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                                                                      GAD_SIZE_320x50.height)];

    self.bannerView.adUnitID = self.adUnitID;
    self.bannerView.delegate = self;
    self.bannerView.rootViewController = self;

    [self.view addSubview:self.bannerView];

    [self.bannerView loadRequest:[self createRequest]];

}



- (GADRequest *)createRequest
{
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

#warning Comment this out before distribution
    request.testDevices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"84ea3d9789cabb0a34176cbb52c0f992", @"abf08fe141b95987d27ac068602605b8", GAD_SIMULATOR_ID, nil];

    return request;
}



- (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view
{
    NSLog(@"Received Ad");

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {
        view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                                self.view.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height,
                                view.frame.size.width,
                                view.frame.size.height);
    }];
}

- (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
}
```

I have seen multiple example's as to how I can embed an ad into the table view, but not anything concrete for how I want to do it. The only thing that I have read in regards to this is that I should put the table view into a container view and then add the ad into that as well. I don't know how I would do that, though, since this is a UITableViewController.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out that the easiest way to accomplish this is by not using a dedicated UITableViewController. I created a UIViewController and added a container controller to the view. From there I subclassed the container controller to be a UITableViewController. I just put all of my code related to the table view in that subclass. I then placed the loading and placement of my ad in the top level UIViewController. Doing it this way means that the ad is embedded into the same view as that container controller. I just made it so that my ad banner is on top of the container. This results in me being able to scroll with the table view and the ad banner not moving.

Comment: Can you put code for this. I also need it, but I am new to iOS programing, so hard to follow just from description.

Comment: @WebOrCode this is a good post about: https://www.appcoda.com/google-admob-ios-swift/